# Worker threads and event loop in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I know how the main thread and event loop are working. However, when it comes to worker threads, some concepts are not adding up for me.

My question is, how NodeJS is handling like 10,000 requests by utilizing **workers**. I mean, initially we only have 4 threads right?

I am looking for the concept behind this, not specifically for a solution to a problem I have now.

Comment: This is a big topic. Please provide a more specific question. Maybe, show your "concept" in dummy code and show what you have achieved and what exactly is not working.

Comment: Is it enough???